# NoClassDefFoundError - spigot plugin java

Tags: java, bukkit

**For some reason when I try using my command it prints an error: NoClassDefFoundError**

(I am a noob to java still)
my main file:

```java
package test;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
public class plugin extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("Ready!");
        getCommand("test").setExecutor(new Test(this));
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Bye!");
    }
}
```

And the command file:

```java
package test;
import app.netlify.eggsnham07plugin.Logger;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

public class Test implements CommandExecutor {
private plugin plugin;
public Test(plugin plugin) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
}
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        Logger.info("Command used!"+args.length);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then the file I imported:

```java
//author eggsnham07
package app.netlify.eggsnham07plugin;
public class Logger {
    public static void info(String content) {
        System.out.println("[INFO]: " + content);
    }
    public static void warn(String content) {
        System.out.println("WARN]: "+content);
    }
}
```

plugin.yml:

```yaml
name: MyPlugin
main: test.plugin
version: 1.0
api-version: 1.16
commands:
   test:
      usage: /<command>
```

every time I use the command /test arg1 arg2 it prints the error above, here is the stacktrace:

```
[10:09:34] [Server thread/WARN]: Unexpected exception while parsing console command "test arg1 arg2"
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'test' in plugin MyPlugin v1.0
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:762) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:747) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:387) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:356) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1008) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:847) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: app/netlify/eggsnham07plugin/Logger
        at test.Test.onCommand(Test.java:13) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:3014-Spigot-73fb609-b7eed25]
        ... 9 more
```

I tried searching for similar issues but found none,
any help is appreciated!

EDIT: i got it to work in a different project and i did that by adding it to my pom.xml but it won't work for my plugin yet

Comment: Where is `Logger.java` and `Test.java` in your project's file structure?  Do their file paths match the package statement?

Comment: the Logger.java is in a separate project and Test.java is in the save package as plugin.java and i did add the Logger.java package to my buildpath

Comment: sorry same not save

Comment: Wait a sec can't i just put the dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: How do you add the logger project to your buildpath?  I'll admit IDE functionality is my weakpoint, but I think it's likely that's the root of your problem.

Comment: i would export the project then configure buildpath of the plugin and add external jar file, and yes i think you're right

Comment: If ur using eclipse u add tht project logger as dependcies project to other project try to run it via eclipse.

Comment: the thing is I need to run it in a Minecraft server I can't run it in eclipse, but yes I did add it as a dependency

Comment: For a spigot plugin, you need to declare inter-plugin dependencies in the `plugin.yml` for the project. Otherwise they may not load in an appropriate order, causing your plugin to register commands incorrectly. In other words, add the `netlify` dependency to any `plugin.yml` for a project using it.

Comment: thanks i will try that

Comment: actually how would i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just made a new package and class inside of my project and it works so I will be using that now

EDIT: I found out what Rouge meant, I needed to export the Logger project as a plugin and depend it in the plugin.yml